# Jest: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'print' of '_graphql.default' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm new to using Jest and I'm trying to test my helper function.
I'm not using any Typescript at the moment.

This is the error I get when I run `npm run test`:

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'print' of '_graphql.default' as it is undefined.`

**helper.test.js**:

```
import getDuplicateError from '../../helpers/auth'

test('Check if email already exists', () => {
  error = "duplicate_email_key";
  expect(getDuplicateError(error)).toBe(true);
})
```

**auth.js**:

```
import graphql from "graphql";
const { print } = graphql;

export const getDuplicateError = (errors) => {
  /*...*/ // Actual implementation doesn't use print
};
```

**jest.config.js**

```
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel',
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "babel-jest",
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/"
  ]
};
```

**babel.config.json**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.17",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  }
```

Even though `print` isn't being used for this function (it is used in other ones), the overall issue is that I can't test anything right now because of this issue, and will also need to be able to use it for other functions.

Is there a configuration that I need for destructuring to work? Am I not able to use destructuring on other libraries?
Will definitely prefer to be able to destructure like this because I use a lot of destructuring in my code.

Let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Answer (score 5):

try to import like this

```
import * as graphql from "graphql";
const {print}=graphql;
```

`graphql` is not exported from `graphql` package and hence it is `undefined`. Again when you try to destructure `print` from it, It is throwing error.

Comment: This worked too! How come I need to do `* as graphql` and can't just name it `graphql`?

Comment: you are trying to import default export from `graphql` but I believe there is no deafult export. There are only individual exports and hence doing `* as graphql` groups all those individual exports under the name `graphql`

Comment: So doing this method works for testing, but when I try to use this for my actual server, it gives me `SyntaxError: The requested module 'graphql' does not provide an export named 'print'`. Is there another way to go about this? Currently thinking about mocking it instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had to provide a mock for this one for it to ignore the destructure. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this but this is one solution to go past it. If someone knows of another way to go about it, I'd appreciate other responses!

```
 jest.mock(
    'graphql',
    () => {
      const mPrint = { t: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('test') };
      return {
        print: jest.fn(() => mPrint),
      };
    },
    { virtual: true },
  );
```